# Can I placed the reusable component's service in core module in Angular according to the mentioned scenario

Tags: angular, typescript, directory-structure, file-structure

├── src 
│ ├── app 
│ │ ├── core 
│ │ │ ├── services 
│ │ │ ├── core.module.ts 
│ │ ├── shared 
│ │ │ ├── produt-form 
│ │ │ │ ├── product-form.component.ts|html|css 
│ │ │ │ ├── product-form.service.ts 
│ │ │ │

I have 2 modules **core** and **shared**. I have **product-form** component in **shared** module. and also that **product-form** has **product-form.service**. I use that service to format the form data and return it again to the **product-form.component**. that service only use by **product-form**.
 so I need to know, can I placed the **product-form.service** in **product-form** component like above structure? or should I placed it in **core** module services folder?

I am a beginner for angular.

thank you.

Comment: Storing it within the "product-form" folder might be preferable if it will exclusively serve the component, or alternatively, you could consider treating the "product form" as a feature module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. There are few approached in design:

1. Keep all services separate.
2. Keep dedicated service in scope of component.

```
src
 |-app
 |  |-core
 |     |-services
 |-shared
 |  |-components
 |  |  |-my-component
 |  |    |-my-component.component.html
 |  |    |-my-component.compoennt.ts
 |  |    |-my-component.service.ts
```

But if you will ask me how I would do, I will create a library and place there all my shared servies and components. In this case they will bake separately in library and the main application will call only what it's needed.

```
projects
 |-my-library
 |  |-src
 |  |  |-lib
 |  |     |-components
 |  |     | |-my-component.component.html
 |  |     | |-my-component.component.ts
 |  |     |-services
 |  |     | |-my-component.service.ts
src
 |-app
 |  |-core
 |  |  |-services
 | ...
```

If you want to read more about libraries: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries